# Unity Redraw canvas graphic on Update()

Tags: unity, graphics, gui

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DrawLoad : Graphic
{
    protected override void OnPopulateMesh(VertexHelper vh)
    {
        //==========================
        float r = rectTransform.rect.height / 2.0f;
        //float widthFactor = (rectTransform.rect.width / 2.0f) - r;
        float y = r;
        float x = 0.0f;
        int t = 20;                     // t = total vertices
        float a = 360.0f / (t-1);       // angle delta/differences between each vertex
        float aC = 0.0f;                // incrementing angles  from 0 --> 360
        int maxi = t - 1;
        Vector2[] vtR = new Vector2[t];
        UIVertex[] uivR = new UIVertex[t];

        vh.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i <= maxi; i++)
        {
            y = r * Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * aC);
            x = r * Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * aC);
            vtR[i] = new Vector2(x, y);
            aC += a;

            uivR[i] = UIVertex.simpleVert;
            uivR[i].position = vtR[i];//0,0
            uivR[i].color = Color.green;
            vh.AddVert(uivR[i]);
        }



        // ======== add center point ========
        Vector2 center = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);
        UIVertex c = UIVertex.simpleVert;
        c.position = center;//0,0
        c.color = Color.green;
        vh.AddVert(c);


        for (int i = 0; i <= maxi; i++)
        {
            vh.AddTriangle(t, i, i + 1);// use indexes, don't use count, start from 0
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < uivR.Length; i++)
        {
            uivR[i].color = Color.green;
            vh.SetUIVertex(uivR[i],i);
        }

    }
}
```

Hi, I wish to change the color dynamically of each assigned triangles.
I have these code modified from Unity documentation and I tried the SetUIVertex method but it doesn't seems to work. What is the proper way to redraw the vertices.
I want to make it in MonoBehavior.Update(). Any helps would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:
**The shorst answer** is using `SetAllDirty()` will do.

**A better alternative:**

is using others' source code/utility to draw shape and update circle (unfortunately).

> Go to [bitbucket.org/UnityUIExtensions](https://bitbucket.org/UnityUIExtensions/unity-ui-extensions/downloads/) and download the .unitypackage

> Go to your Unity project and Import the package

> Don't need to import everything but import only

  1. unity-ui-extensions > Scripts > Primitives > UICircle.cs

  2. unity-ui-extensions > Scripts > Primitives > UIPrimitiveBase.cs

  3. unity-ui-extensions > Scripts > Utility > SetPropertyUtility.cs

> Create an UI image under canvas

> Remove the Image Component

> Assign "UICircle.cs" into Image object

> In you game `Update()` script, assign values like `GameObject.Find("Image").GetComponent<UICircle>().FIllPercent -= 1`

> will dynamically change the circle draw percentage.